# Randomly take wrong answers of a quiz question from dataframe column, instead of doing by hand

Tags: r, r-markdown, learnr

I try to make a kind of learning tool using `learnr` package. We have one question and for answers where one is the correct one:

Instead of putting in eachtime a wrong answer by hand I would like to take the WRONG answers randomly from the dataframe:

```
df1 <- tibble(letters = LETTERS, Number = 1:26)
```

How can I make to take randomly cell values from column `Number` for answer 1, 2, and 4. The correct answer is answer Nr.3.

In the first step I have tried to use `deparse(substitute(df1[1,2]))` instead of `1`, but failed.

````
---
title: "Tutorial"
output: learnr::tutorial
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(learnr)
library(tidyverse)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
df1 <- tibble(letters = LETTERS, Number = 1:26)
```


Question 1:

```{r quiz}
# This works not
quiz(
  question("Which number has E?",
    answer(deparse(substitute(df1[1,2]))),
    answer(deparse(substitute(df1[4,2]))),
    answer(deparse(substitute(df1[5,2])), correct = TRUE),
    answer(deparse(substitute(df1[8,2])))
  ),
  # This one works
  question("Which number has E?",
    answer("1"),
    answer("4"),
    answer("5", correct = TRUE),
    answer("8")
  )
)
```
````

output:
[image]

Comment: I somehow don't understand your question. Are you looking for something (in the right context) like `test <- sample(df1[df1$letters != "E",]$Number, size = 3)` combined with `answer(df1[[test[1],1]])`, `answer(df1[[test[2],1]])` and so on?

Comment: Small correction: `answer(test[1])` instead of `answer(df1[[test[1],1]])`

Comment: HI Martin Gal. Goood to see you. your approach is promising but somehow I can not implement it in rmarkdown chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to convert to `character` class

````
---
title: "Tutorial"
output: learnr::tutorial
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(learnr)
library(dplyr)    
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
df1 <- tibble(letters = LETTERS, Number = 1:26)
```


Question 1:

```{r quiz}
# This works not
quiz(
 question("Which number has E?",
       answer(as.character(df1[[2]][1])),
       answer(as.character(df1[4,2])),
       answer(as.character(df1[5,2]), correct = TRUE),
       answer(as.character(df1[8,2]))         
  ),
  # This one works
  question("Which number has E?",
       answer("1"),
       answer("4"),
       answer("5", correct = TRUE),
       answer("8")
  )
 )
 ```
````

-output

[image]