# How to exclude values from random selection

Tags: r, dataframe, random, subset

This is independent but related to this question [Randomly take wrong answers of a quiz question from dataframe column, instead of doing by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70908141/randomly-take-wrong-answers-of-a-quiz-question-from-dataframe-column-instead-of)

Using the `mtcars` dataset I now have managed to randomly select one value from a certain column: In this example from `cyl` column.

```
mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars), 1),2]
```

This code will give randomly
`[1] 6` or `[1] 8` or ...

Now I want to exclude one certain value to be chosen, in this example say `cyl==8`.
I would store the value in a vector like:

```
not_select <- 8

mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars), 1),2]
```

My question: How can I integrate `not_select` in `mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars), 1),2]`

Expected Output: The random sample should not include `8`

**UPDATE:
e.g. the output should be:
`6` or `4`**

UPDATE II due to unclear situation:

I want to select from column `cyl` one value randomly. This value should not be for example `8`. So the value will be `4` or `6`.

Explanation: `8` is the correct answer. And I am constructing randomly false answers with the other values (e.g. 4 and 6) from `cyl` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn‘t you just add a filtering condition based on not_select?

```
mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars), 1) & mtcars$cyl != not_select, 2]
```

Update: how about:

```
not_select <- 8

draw_cyl <- sample(unique(mtcars$cyl[mtcars$cyl != not_select]), 1)

mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl == draw_cyl) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 1) %>%
  pull(cyl)
```

Or as suggested by TarJae themselve (so I don‘t own any credit for it!):

```
mtcars[sample(which (mtcars[,2] != not_select), 1), 2]
```

Comment: This looks good, but gives a vector of all values that are not 8. I would need just one value that is not 8,

Comment: So you want to randomly select one 8 out of all sampled 8‘s? I‘m a bit confused, tbh, what the expected output should be in terms of 8‘s? I.e. you said the uodate should be 4 or 6, and the vector I‘m producing does only contqin 4 and 6, no?

Comment: Or do you want to sample just ONE row with a 4 and ONE row with a 6?

Comment: I want to select from column `cyl` one value randomly. This value should not be for example `8`. So the value will be `4` or `6`. Explanation: `8` is the correct answer. And I am constructing randomly false answers with the other values (e.g. 4 and 6) from cyl column.

Comment: With your help I found the answer. `mtcars[sample(which (mtcars[,2] != not_select), 1), 2]`. Please integrate it to your answer and I will accept.

Comment: I updated my answer with another potential solution. Would that work as well?

Comment: Exactly. but please add the version with which in your answer! Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, another way -

```
tmp <- mtcars[, 2] 
sample(tmp[tmp != not_select], 1)
```

The above gives the probability of selecting each value based on their occurrence in the dataset. If you want the probability to be equal irrespective of how many times they occur you may only consider `unique` values.

```
tmp <- unique(mtcars[, 2])
sample(tmp[tmp != not_select], 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This recursive function will run on itself again if the output matches `not_selected`.

```
exclude_not_selected <- function(not_selected) {
  value <- mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars), 1),2] 
  if (value == not_selected) {
    exclude_not_selected(not_selected)
  } else {
    return(value)
  }
}

exclude_not_selected(8)
[1] 4
```