# Line break or soft break after paste

Tags: r, dataframe, paste, line-breaks, learnr

I have this dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(letters = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Number = 1:4, 
    Info = c("additionalinfo", "additionalinfo", "additionalinfo", 
    "additionalinfo")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))


  letters Number           Info
1       A      1 additionalinfo
2       B      2 additionalinfo
3       C      3 additionalinfo
4       D      4 additionalinfo
```

**I try to** add a new column combining two columns with a soft break or line break:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(answer = paste(Number, Info, sep = " \n" ))
```

**Desired output:**

[image]

Background:
Within this project [Randomly take wrong answers of a quiz question from dataframe column, instead of doing by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70908141/randomly-take-wrong-answers-of-a-quiz-question-from-dataframe-column-instead-of) I want to add the answer with a **soft break** or **line break**

It should print like here in the first question. Which number has E?:
[image]

Comment: Do you want the output to print like that in R, or do you want to export it somewhere (e.g., a cdv file) where it looks like that?

Comment: I have tried to show what I mean with a picture.

Comment: @TarJae isn't the output that is showed in DonaldSeinen's post?  I tried that and it seems to be working for me

Comment: I just arrived now there and pasted to my script. I am exploring just now! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For shiny-rendered docs inline HTML using line break `<br>` could be used.

````
---
title: "Tutorial"
output: learnr::tutorial
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---

#```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(learnr); library(dplyr); library(glue)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
df <- structure(list(letters = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Number = 1:4, 
    Info = c("additionalinfo", "additionalinfo", "additionalinfo", 
    "additionalinfo")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
df <- df %>% mutate(answer = glue("{Number}<br>{Info}"))
#```

```{r quiz}
# This works not
quiz(
 question("Which number has E?",
       answer(df[[4]][1]),
       answer(df[[4]][2]),
       answer(df[[4]][3], correct = TRUE),
       answer(df[[4]][4])         
  ),
  # This one works
  question("Which number has E?",
       answer("1"),
       answer("4"),
       answer("5", correct = TRUE),
       answer("8")
  )
 )
````

Comment: Bravo Donald Seinen. Works great!.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the `answer` column without displaying the entire dataframe you can try

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(answer = paste(Number, Info, sep = "\n" )) %>% 
  pull(answer) %>% 
  cat(sep = "\n")
```

```
1
additionalinfo
2
additionalinfo
3
additionalinfo
4
additionalinfo
```

Or, item by item

```r
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(answer = paste(Number, Info, sep = "\n" ))

cat(df2$answer[1])
cat(df2$answer[2])
...
cat(df2$answer[n])
```